# QField: adding dynamic basemap

Tags: qgis, basemap, qfield, qfieldsync

Using QField on an Android Phone, I wanted to import a project created on QGIS 3.24, using QField sync plugin. I did this with earlier versions of QField, but with the newest version 2.1.4, it doesn't work like it used to.

I read [these instructions](https://www.opengis.ch/de/2022/03/05/qfield-users-sit-down-we-need-to-talk-about-storage-access-on-android%EF%BF%BC/) to get the right folder location. I am able to correctly add the project and open it in QField: the point layer I want to visualize shows correctly.

However, the OpenStreetMap basemap, added as XYZ-tile in QGIS, seems to be saved in a fixed resolution. So zooming in and out, the basemap does not change at all.

I am confused as in earlier versions, I could easily use several XYZ tiles (OSM, Google maps etc.) in the same project. Now, Qfield sync plugin seems to expect a basemap that is saved as a raster in GPKG format. When I deactivate the basemap, I get just a white background, even if I activate on of the other layers based on XYZ-tiles (second screenshot below).

I, however, want to have a dynamic basemap, accessed online, that changes resolution as it was possible in earlier versions.

How to achieve that?

EDIT:

I realised that the problem is connected to a problem with CRS (see [here for more details](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/432881/qfield-project-shows-wrong-gps-position)). The saved geopackage static raster basemap does not show in the same position as the dynamic XYZ-tiles basemap - both are way off and at completely different scales of each other.

*Settings in QGIS*
[image]

*Settings in Qfield: basemap is deactivated, OSM and Google Satellite layers activated. Still, backgound is empty:*
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was solved by de- and re-installing QField. The problem was indeed caused by a wrong geolocation - the imported file-based layers (vector and static raster basemap) were located completely off the map canvas that showed the XYZ-tiles and in a completely different scale.