# Qfield project shows wrong GPS position

Tags: qgis, gps, qfield, position, qfieldsync

I created a project in QGIS with project CRS in `EPSG:3857`, packed it for Qfield with [Qfield Sync plugin](https://docs.qfield.org/get-started/tutorials/get-started-qfs/) and saved it to my Android device. When I open the project there with Qfield and activate GPS, my position shows in a completely wrong place: northwest of Svalbard islands somewhere in the Ocean (see first screenshot below). I am, however, in Zurich, Switzerland.

Using other apps (like OsmAnd) on the same phone with same GPS receiver, I get the correct position. So the problem is obviously with Qfield.

If I zoom to my point layer an then zoom out, I realise that the points are way off the OSM basemap: see second screenshot below. My region of interest shows up, GPS position is somewhere down. When I pan to the GPS position (blue dot), I have to heavily zoom in to see the dynamic OSM basemap. So my point layer + the saved static raster basemap is completely wrong as concerns position **and** scale. So the problem seems to be connected with [this one here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/432857/qfield-adding-dynamic-basemap).

I have no clue what went wrong. How to solve the problem?

*My position as it appears when activating GPS. Zooming in to the blue dot does not help:*
[image]

*Region of interest with the static raster OSM basemap, saved as gpkg file by the Qfield Sync plugin on the upper part; my position (blue dot) at the lower part. The dynamic OSM basemap (XYZ tiles) does not show as it is zoomed out too much:*
[image]

*Zooming in the the GPS position does not solve the problem - it still shows a location NW of Svalbard:*
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What exactly caused the problem is still unclear to me, however, I found a solution by simply deinstalling and installing QField again. I use the same Qfield version as before (2.1.4), so there seems to be an issue with the updated Qfield version.

Comment: I had the same exact problem. Uninstalling and re-installing the android app fixed it.